# Como usar o foreach para mostrar varios valores de arrays para a view em uma tabela

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com uma dúvida para conseguir utilizar um *array* de *PHP* para mostrar os valores dentro de uma tabela. O princípio é armazenar os valores em um *array* para depois utilizar um **foreach** para inserir os valores dentro de uma tabela em *HTML* na minha *view* do **Laravel**. como exemplo ao código abaixo.

```
<tbody>                         
  <tr>
       @foreach($dataTable as $dt)

           <td class="text-center">
                {{$dt->valor1}}
           </td>
           <td class="text-center">
                {{$dt->valor2}}
           </td>
           <td class="text-center">
                {{$dt->valor3}}
           </td>
      @endforeach
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

No meu controller, inseri 3 tipos de *array* dentro de outro *array*, que acabei transformando esse mesmo *array* em objeto, como mostra o exemplo abaixo.

```
$dataTable[] = (object) ['valor1'=>$valor1, 'valor2'=>$valor2, 'valor3'=>$valor3];
```

Acabei utilizando um teste no proprio **Controller** do **Laravel** utilizando o seguinte código abaixo, para ver como os valores estão sendo utilizados.

```
foreach($dataTable as $dt){
     dd($dt);
}
```

Os valores deram o seguinte resultado.

```
   {#418 ▼
      +"valor1": array:7 [▶]
      +"valor2": array:7 [▶]
      +"valor3": array:7 [▶]
    }
```

Porém a minha *view* com o código **HTML**, não está funcionando utilizando os valores dessa maneira. Ela aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Estou utilizando o framework Laravel. Existe alguma maneira com a mesma ideia de inserir os valores na tabela que funcione e seja viável? Tentei percorrer sendo um array e não um objeto e mesmo assim na view não mostra funcionalidade. Em vez disso, aparece erros como:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Eu considero estranho pelo fato de que dentro do controller funciona direito. Porém dentro do **HTML** com as tabelas, sempre persiste nos erros.

Comment: Mostra o código desse controller e o dd do $datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve converter antes seus objetos e ser um array de objeto para colher os dados da forma como quer:

Todos os **$objeto** deverão ter o mesmo atributo valor para ser usado dest maneira e não valor1, valor2 e etc.

```
$arr = [$objeto, $objeto2, $objeto3];

return view('minha.view', compact('arr'));
```

Na view

```
@foreach($arr as $item)
  {{$item->valor}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Nesse caso. Qual a funcionalidade da função compact? O que ela está fazendo com o array?

Comment: Compact te permite passar mais de um array, para view, por exempo compact(['arr', 'arr2', 'arr3']); Se vc for passar um elemento somente vc pode passar direto se ele for um array, se for um objeto ainda precisará do compact.

Comment: pode passar assim também compact('arr', 'arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3')